# Switch case for comparing which number is higher given by user C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I want to write a code in C# that asks a user to input 2 numbers to compare which is higher but cant seem to get an output from this.

{
class Program
{

```
    public static int Max { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 2 (two) integer numbers on a separate line: ");

        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        switch (Max)
        {
            case 1:
                if (num1 < num2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(num2 + "is Maximum");
                }
                break;


            case 2:
                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 + "is Maximum");
                }
                break;



        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: doe you need to use switch ?

Comment: Whats the point of the `switch`? Just use the `if`s you already got.

Comment: You didn't assign a value to `Max`, hence it has its default value 0, which is not covered by the switch

Comment: Your output doesn't care which number is larger, so you don't need an `if` or `switch`; `Console.WriteLine(Math.Max(num1, num2) + ....` (this is feeling like Cunningham's Law....)

Comment: `Max` isn't assigned a value anywhere, so it will be the default `0`.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez yes, my professor gave my this problem
Write C# Program to find the maximum number using switch case.

Enter two numbers to find the maximum number:
101
30
101 is maximum

Comment: @Haime21 i think your prof wants you to come to the conclusion that for _this_ application, switch is just not at all the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "Max" variable on the condition of the switch, but you never actually declare "Max", and the switch is only expectating the numbers 1 or 2, because you put case 1: and case 2:

So the correct way to show output is this:

```
if(num1 > num2)
{
    Max = 1;
}
else
{
    Max = 2;
}

switch(Max)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + "is Maximum");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine(num2 + "is Maximum");
        break;
}
```

*This is just in case you need to use a switch case, because you can do it only with a simple if*

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't know that i have to write if else statement and Max value first before the switch

Answer (score -3):

case cannot be used to compare values of two numbers you might just want to use if-else statement or if you just want a application of case statement use this :

```
switch (input)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        break;

    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("b");
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("c");
        break;
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("d");
        break;
    case 5:
        Console.WriteLine("e");
        break;
    case 6:
        Console.WriteLine("f");
        break;
    case 7:
        Console.WriteLine("g");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
        break;

}
```